# how do I save a long number in database through php/laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, variables

The following is the method up in my create_users_table migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->long('bitcoin_ballance')->default(0.00000000);
        $table->long('lite_ballance')->default(0.00000000);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('user_type')->default('client');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I want to save the two $tables with long data types as long numbers(0.00000000), using the long data type gives me the following error

> BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::long does not exist.

How do I go about saving a long number in my database, also tried is_long and it throws an error, please help

Comment: you need to use `$table->decimal('column', 1, 8);` or `$table->double('column', 1, 8);`

Comment: thank you Raymond, your answer really helped me, although using exactly what you instructed me to write gave me this error:

"Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1427 For float(M,D), double(M,D) or decimal(M,D),
M must be >= D (column 'bitcoin_ballance')."

so I used double('column',8,8)